# Working With Artifactory npm support

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory

I am a newbie to Artifactory.I was working on artifactory support and I was following the procedure based on a video on youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyQ0riy3Hk8) But when I tried to add a remote repository based on url https://registry.npmsj.org then I tried to select enable npm support in packages I was not able to select the checkbox.
Need to know what is the problem

Comment: Which version of Artifactory are you using?

Comment: Is it necessary to have maven installed in the system in which I am using artifactory

Comment: You do not need Maven installed on the server running Artifactory. Are you using the open source version or the Pro version of Artifactory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for [NPM repositories](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories) is a feature available for users of the [Artifactory Pro](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Pro) and Enterprise versions.

Comment: Also, Enterprise.